# How to use LIKE to extract specific ID row in SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server

I have this issue around this SQL script that I want your assistance with.

I have records with the following data:

```
ID         AGE
-----------------
AB1001      20
AB1002      21
OPEI112     12
ABI1001     25
ABI1002     28
OPEI220     14
AB1003      30
TI2100      19
AB1004      32
ABI1003     26
ABI1004     10
```

I want to display all ID's start with ***ABI,OPEI,TI*** I don't want to see ID's that start with ***`AB`***. I use a SQL `SELECT` statement, I have tried the following:

```
SELECT ID 
FROM TableID 
WHERE ID LIKE 'ABI%'AND ID LIKE 'OPEI%' AND ID LIKE 'TI%'
```

This didn't return the expected output because it contain ***AB***, so I tried this which displays all the records

```
SELECT ID 
FROM TableID 
WHERE ID NOT LIKE 'AB%'
```

This too didn't return the expected result because it also exclude the ID's with ***ABI***, but displays all the records.

I need any suggestion that will display all record ID's without ***`AB`***

Thank you

Comment: `SELECT ID from TableID WHERE ID LIKE 'ABI%'` looks right. Can you explain how its output was wrong?

Comment: Thanks, from my question you'll see i tried using that query i have other ID's like TI,OPEI that will be excluded that is why i adjust the question

Comment: "This didn't return the expected output because it contain AB, so I tried this which displays all the records".   No it doesn't. Your query is correct, your assumptions are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

See your first query , You need to use OR statement instead of AND

as below ,

```
SELECT ID 
FROM TableID 
WHERE ID LIKE 'ABI%'OR ID LIKE 'OPEI%' OR ID LIKE 'TI%'
```

Comment: Many thanks, i just realise that my question may not be presenting other ID's like OPEI,TI and others that will be excluded if i use your suggestion, that is why i adjust the question again, I hope i can get help from you. thanks

Comment: @Abraham1973 this is what you requested in adjusted question , isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
create table #temp (id varchar(20), age int)
insert into #temp values 
('AB1001', '20'), ('AB1002', 21), ('ABI1001', 25), ('ABI1002', 28), ('AB1003', 30), ('AB1004', 32),
('ABI1003', 26), ('ABI1004', 10)

select * from #temp where id like 'ABI%'

drop table #temp
```

The output is as follows

```
id      age
ABI1001 25
ABI1002 28
ABI1003 26
ABI1004 10
```

Here all id starts with ABI.

Comment: Many thanks, i just realise that my question may not be presenting other ID's like OPEI,TI and others that will be excluded if i use your suggestion, that is why i adjust the question again, I hope i can get help from you. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your "AND"s to "OR"s:

```
SELECT ID 
FROM TableID 
WHERE ID LIKE 'ABI%'
    OR ID LIKE 'OPEI%' 
    OR ID LIKE 'TI%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Select * from TableID where ID not in (AB1001,AB1002,ABI1001,ABI1002,AB1003,AB1004,ABI1003 ,ABI1004 )